# c# method overload, with other methods

Tags: c#, loops, methods, overloading

I need help getting both to run, but individually they run when i do them on their own. The first loop generates (but hides) 20 random numbers and the second adds and displays the value with the sum but i am not sure how to combine.

assignment:

You will have Main in which you will declare 4 variables, a loop that will call a method that will return a random number, a call to a void calculate method which will take an integer random value variable, a by ref average variable, a literal value of 20 as arguments and which will calculate an average, followed by a console writeline to display the average.  This will be followed by a loop that will execute 5 times and will prompt for and assign a double value to a double variable and then call an overload of the calculate method and pass the entered value and a byref total variable.  In the overloaded calculate method you will accumulate the passed value into the total variable.  After the loop you will display the total.

The output might look similar to this:

The average of the 20 random numbers is 71

Enter a double value 10.0

Enter a double value 20.0

Enter a double value 30.0

Enter a double value 40.0

Enter a double value 50.1

The total is 150.1

Press any key to continue .

```
using System;


namespace week7
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

int randomNumber;//hold random
double average = 0;//hold average
double total = 0;//hold total
double manualEntry = 0; //input entry 

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)//20 times
{
randomNumber = getRandom();//by reference

total = total + randomNumber;//by reference
}

calculate(total, ref average, 20);



Console.WriteLine("The average of the 20 random numbers is {0}", average);

total = 0;
Console.WriteLine();//adds space

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{ 
Console.Write("Enter a double value ");
manualEntry = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
calculate(manualEntry, ref total);



}
Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}",total);

}

static int getRandom()
{
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
return randomGenerator.Next(1,101);
}

//pass the total of the random values, the average variable by reference, and the literal value of 20.


// the entry taken from the console and the variable to hold the total by    reference. 
private static void calculate(double consoleInput, ref double total)
{
total += consoleInput;
}
//pass the total of the random values, the average variable by reference, and   the literal value of 20.
private static void calculate(double total, ref double average, double          denominator)
{
average = total / denominator;
}
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two main methods.  You should make them their own void methods and call them both from a single main.

Comment: After comparing your problem statement to your code.... I think you have too many problems for this to be a good SO question.  Start by looking at the Main() flow and the methods that the question indicates you should create.

Comment: I would suggest learning how to set and use Breakpoints. This will help you debug on your own for school, especially when a professor is not there to help.

Comment: Static methods cannot be overriden, and `Main()` definitely shouldn't have two implementations.

Comment: I really suggest you start reading the book from the very beginning again. It's not hard, and you will spot the problems by yourself very soon.

Comment: also start googling how to use the debugger.. also why do you have to Mains..?

Comment: Cheers Ethan, hadnt thought of that..

Answer (score 2):

You have very explicit instructions that you didn't seem to follow. I'm ignoring most of the body of your question and will instead attempt to get you started on your title question by showing you the signature for the `Calculate()` method and an overload for the `Calculate()` method.

Calculate method: "a void calculate method which will take an integer random value variable, a by ref average variable, a literal value of 20 as arguments" (note: I don't know what your teacher means by "a literal value of 20" as an argument, so I used a default value)

```
void Calculate(int randomInteger, ref double average, int literal = 20)
{

}
```

Overloaded Calculate method:
"an overload of the calculate method and pass the entered value and a byref total variable"

```
void Calculate(double enteredValue, ref double total)
{

}
```

Comment: could you show me where and what i would need to add for displaying the 20 random numbers? just to check the math and see if its running right?